# Solution of an ordinary differential equation is defined over an open interval

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given an ordinary differential equation, I read the definition of a solution (http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Definitions.aspx)

> A solution to a differential equation on an interval  $\alpha<t<\beta$  is any function  which satisfies the differential equation in question on the interval $\alpha<t<\beta$.

My question is why did we specify in the definition that it would be an interval (and not a disjoint union of intervals for example) and also why the interval is open? is there a problem in defining a solution over a closed interval? thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mildly annoying to define exactly what the derivative of a function is at $a$ and $b$, if the function is only defined on $[a, b]$, due to the definition of the derivative involving a (two-sided) limit. You can just take a one-sided limit, but here's a specific type of nuisance that might arise. Say you have some ODE $f'(t)=u(f(t), t)$. And suppose some function $f$ is defined on $(a, b+\epsilon)$, and its restriction to $(a, b]$ is a solution to the ODE, meaning the left-hand derivative of $f$ at $b$ is $u(f(b), b)$. What if $f$ is actually non-differentiable at $b$, because the difference quotient at $b$ has a different right-hand limit to its left-hand limit? What if the right-hand derivative of $f$ at $b$ does *not* satisfy the ODE? Do we really want to say that $f$ solves the ODE on $(a, b]$?

It's just not worth dealing with this kind of irritation in an intro class. It's easier to just say that $f$ solves the ODE on $(a, b)$, and then if for some particular ODE there is some interesting phenomenon happening at the end-points of the interval, investigating them as a special case.

Comment: but why should it be an interval? for example $y=\frac{1}{x}$ is a solution of $xy'+y=0$ for any $x\not = 0$ so why not taking $y=\frac{1}{x}$ as a solution on $(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)$ instead of choosing one of these intervals $(-\infty,0)$ or $(0,\infty)$ ? my problem is why restricting the **definition** of a solution on an **interval**

Comment: @palio You could avoid all of the problems I talked about in my answer by just talking about open sets, rather than just open intervals. But since an open set on $\mathbb R$ can always be expressed as a union (even a countable union) of open intervals, you can easily reduce to the case of open intervals. For example, a function is a solution of $xy'=-y$ on $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ iff it's a solution on on the two open intervals $(0, \infty)$ and $(-\infty, 0)$.

Comment: In Zill and Cullen's ''Differential equations" page 6 they say : "But when we say that $y=\frac{1}{x}$ is a solution of this DE, we mean that it is a function defined on an interval $I$ on which it is differentiable and satisfies the equation....Thus we take $I$ to be either $(-\infty,0)$ or $(0,\infty)$".. I hope my question is clear now with the definition emphesising that it should be an interval while $\mathbb R\setminus 0$ is not an interval and with this example emphasising that we should choose **either** $(-\infty,0)$ or (0, \infty)$

Comment: @palio They're just trying to keep it simple for the sake of writing an introductory book. No reasonable person would claim that a function verifying a DE on a non-interval open set isn't a solution to the DE on that open set. The point is, the general case of solutions on open sets reduces easily to the special case of solutions on intervals, so it's enough to just study that.